# Applying SharePoint App Context Authorization to Legacy Web Service

Tags: web-services, authentication, sharepoint-online

I currently have the need to use the legacy OfficialFile.asmx web service to do a SubmitFile against SharePoint Online sites, (since the CSOM doesn't support it) from a SharePoint Provider-hosted app. In order to authenticate the ASMX service, I currently create a SharePointOnlineCredential and then apply the FedAuth cookie to this service. This works great, of course. The issue is, I have to create the SharePointOnlineCredential by explicitly passing a UserName and SecureString Password to the class to create the cookie.

What I need to do is have a way to either:

1. Create a FedAuth cookie from the SPContext created in the SharePoint app already, or
2. Have a way to apply the token(s) created in the SharePoint app applied to the ASMX in a way that will authenticate the service.

Right now I have tried #2, but always have permissions errors. Is it possible to do either of these?

The goal is to say "Hey, I already know who the user is via the SPContext, just pass it to the ASMX and allow this access to the ASMX service.

Make sense?